# Is it possible to get the password from a wps wifi connection?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, password, ios

At school we have two wifi networks, one for teaches and one students, but the teacher network is much faster and is available everywhere in the building. I could connect to it by pressing the wps button on a repeater, but some of my classmates could not because they have iphones (iphones don't have wps). I would like to help them by telling the password, but i don't know if there is a way to retrieve it from this kind of connection. And this is what i'm asking your help for: Can i get the password somehow?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [WPS is insecure](https://sviehb.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf) and the WPS PIN can be used to recover the password.

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigos.androdumpper) and [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tester.wpswpatester) claim to be able to do so if you have root.

However, as pointed out by Izzy the password should also be available as plain text in the file `/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` after you have successfully connected to the network once.

Comment: How can i get the wps pin? I just pressed the button at the back of the router and on my phone and they connected. I didn't type in any pin.  Could you suggest a programe for rooting my phone?

Comment: @LeventeKovács See http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/1465 and feel free to post a new question about rooting your device if it does not appear in that list.